# How to get openCL library for Hi3536 Mali GPU

Tags: opencv

We are using Hi3536 Soc, which has Mali T720 core. The SDK of Hi3536 does not provide examples for OpenCL nor the library. Any suggestions how to get the cross-compiled SDK libraries for Mali T720?

Comment: OpenGL & OpenCL libraries is a part of GPU drivers, and usually should come together with the drivers. Check that your hard vendor install them, or try to install them your self https://developer.arm.com/products/software/mali-drivers

Comment: Drivers are available in the SDK. Even mali.so is available. Unfortunately, OpenCL is not enabled in the mali.so. Checked using command strings | grep clGet as suggested in another forum.

Comment: Have you tried `objdump -TC mali.so | grep -i "cl"`?

Comment: According to the [SDK doc](https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/latest/) you need libarm_compute.so

Comment: You cannot install those drivers yourself. You need to ask the vendor (hisilicon) for those binaries. @VictorGubin, compute library is an additional library that is capable of running on top of neon/opencl. You do not need that libarm_compute.so to just run opencl applications. Unfortunately, there isn't a lot that can be done to get you opencl unless hisilicon gives you the correct mali.so file. :/